why cant i install dependencies on my ReactNative Web?
I'm feeling hopeless now. I'm trying to build a web app using React Native web for my capstone project and I'm having lots of errors installing dependencies. I always get this error on react-scripts, node modules and jests.
Can someone help me please?
Error :
PS C:\WebApp - Copy (2)> npm install react-scripts@latest

npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency    
npm WARN While resolving: jest-watch-typeahead@1.1.0
npm WARN Found: jest@29.7.0
npm WARN node_modules/jest
npm WARN   peerOptional jest@"*" from eslint-plugin-jest@27.9.0
npm WARN   node_modules/eslint-plugin-jest
npm WARN     eslint-plugin-jest@"^27.9.0" from @react-native/eslint-config@0.75.3
npm WARN     node_modules/@react-native/eslint-config
npm WARN   1 more (the root project)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer jest@"^27.0.0 || ^28.0.0" from jest-watch-typeahead@1.1.0
npm WARN node_modules/jest-watch-typeahead      
npm WARN   jest-watch-typeahead@"^1.0.0" from react-scripts@5.0.1
npm WARN   node_modules/react-scripts
npm WARN 
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: jest@28.1.3
npm WARN node_modules/jest
npm WARN   peer jest@"^27.0.0 || ^28.0.0" from jest-watch-typeahead@1.1.0
npm WARN   node_modules/jest-watch-typeahead    
npm WARN     jest-watch-typeahead@"^1.0.0" from react-scripts@5.0.1
npm WARN     node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: react-scripts@5.0.1
npm ERR! Found: typescript@5.0.4
npm ERR! node_modules/typescript
npm ERR!   peerOptional typescript@">=4.9.5" from cosmiconfig@9.0.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-config/node_modules/cosmiconfig
npm ERR!     cosmiconfig@"^9.0.0" from @react-native-community/cli-config@14.1.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-config
npm ERR!       @react-native-community/cli-config@"14.1.0" from @react-native-community/cli@14.1.0
npm ERR!       node_modules/@react-native-community/cli
npm ERR!         @react-native-community/cli@"14.1.0" from react-native@0.75.3
npm ERR!         node_modules/react-native      
npm ERR!       1 more (@react-native-community/cli-doctor)
npm ERR!   peer typescript@">= 2.7" from fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@6.5.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin
npm ERR!     fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@"^6.5.0" from react-dev-utils@12.0.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-dev-utils       
npm ERR!       react-dev-utils@"^12.0.1" from react-scripts@5.0.1
npm ERR!       node_modules/react-scripts       
npm ERR!         react-scripts@"5.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   3 more (ts-api-utils, tsutils, the root project)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peerOptional typescript@"^3.2.1 || ^4" from react-scripts@5.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!   react-scripts@"5.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: typescript@4.9.5
npm ERR! node_modules/typescript
npm ERR!   peerOptional typescript@"^3.2.1 || ^4" from react-scripts@5.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!     react-scripts@"5.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-09-17T09_36_44_394Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-09-

I tried different solutions given by different tutorials and open AI, but I don't know if I'm doing it right or I just haven't found the real solution.

This question is similar to: Unable to resolve dependency tree error when installing npm packages. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
